# Hard reseting takes no effect in Android

Tags: android, bootloader, rom, fastboot

I'm trying to hard reset my phone with a password, but hard reseting in fastboot runs fine, but when it reboots, nothing is erased at all.

I also tried to install CWM and TWRP Recovery, and when the device is rebooted, nothing changes. The only message I get when installing theses recoveries is "Mismatched partition size (recovery)", but it seems just a warning, not an error.

I also tried to remove the password, but it requires CWM or TWRP to work, so no success.

I also tried to reinstall the current stock ROM (Kitkat 4.4), and Lollipop (5.0, 5.1) using *Minimal ADB and Fastboot*, and I get no error doing that, but when the device reboots, I still see nothing has changed.

Is there a way to REALLY wipe everything, to start installing any ROM from scratch?

I'm using Mogo G 1st Generation Dual Sim (XT-1033).

**EDIT:** Now I've managed a trick to only load in cache CWM or TWRP, but the wipe data didn't work either.

Comment: I assume you mean your data is marked as deleted but not actually gone? I was surprised but found this link: http://www.ubergizmo.com/how-to/wipe-android-phone-tablet/. It would seem encrypting the phone forced it to delete everything.